# Best way to setup NIC priorities

Tags: networking, network-adapter

I have two public internet connections A and B.

So far I have connect these 2 connections to a win 7 PC with 2 NICs and I have setup the NIC priority through  [Network connections] - [Advanced] - [Advanced Settings] - [Adapters and Bindings] - [A then B]

But when I testing it with Youtube OR download, I see all the traffic is on B connection which I ve setup as priority #2.

I did reboot after change the settings, the result was the same.

What is the proper way to specify a certain network connection on PC?

Should I use 2 NICs or just use one NIC with 2 different IPs?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you hoping to do here?  What do you think two nics will give you?  Anyway, see the interface, and per-route metrics.

Comment: There is just a request that this PC must be on network A, The NIC priority has been setup as A then B, also Metrics has been setup as A is lowest value. When I do the test, somehow, the traffic still going through B network...

Comment: A network is directly to internet and B is internal, we need to have B network connected as well.

Comment: what interface is your default route using?

Comment: @RootLoop it is all about setting up routes properly.